# jQuery replace multiple elements using class

Tags: jquery

I want to replace all the `spans` with a `div`.
When I run this code only one element gets replaced.
How to change this code so that the script affects all the `spans`?

*I have tried to use clone(), but it didn't work.*

```
$flexBox = $("<div></div>");
$(".overlayBox").replaceWith($flexBox);

<span class="overlayBox"></span>
<span class="overlayBox"></span>
<span class="overlayBox"></span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`replaceAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/) method:

```
$flexBox.replaceAll(".overlayBox");​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4VHVC/

Comment: Your solution doesn't work at all, even the first element doesn't get replaced.

Comment: @RegisteredUser It works if you write it like vice versa. Check the demo from the answer.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Do you check **DEMO** from the answer? Mine works perfectly. `div` blocks are displayed in red.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Tested and it worked fine in FF12, Chrome and IE 7.

Comment: Sure the demo works, but the code fails to work inside my app

Comment: @RegisteredUser Check that you use `$flexBox.replaceAll(...)` but not `$(".overlayBox").replaceAll(...)`.

Comment: @RegisteredUser. Please [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134490/173320) regarding, "doesn't work"...

Comment: Not sure what that Meta nonsense is, but I found the problem to be me defining $flexBox as a global variable. Not sure why this should matter but after moving `var $flexBox` into function's scope, it began to work.

Comment: @RegisteredUser It really depends on the situation. Good that you found the problem.